# JSON select data

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to do something really easy: Select JSON data by its key but somehow it doesn't work.

This is my jQuery function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_add_question",
    data: {
        title: function() {
            return title.val();
        },
        text: function() {
            return text.val();
        },
        slide_id: function() {
            return aside.attr('id');
        },
    },
    success: function(data) {
        aside.append("<h3>" + data.title + "</h3>");
        aside.append("<p>" + data.text + "</p>");
    }
});
```

This is what my server returns:

```
{"text": "b", "title": "a"}
```

and the data in the chrome debugger looks like this:

```
data: "{"text": "b", "title": "a"}"
```

But it keeps saying the data.title/data.text are undefined. 
(I also tried data['title'] and data[title])

Comment: have you set json header for response.?

Comment: **For JSON:**

    `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

**For JSON-P:**

    `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`

Comment: Why does the `data` object for the request contain functions?

Comment: As you can see `"{"text": "b", "title": "a"}"` is a string. You have to parse the JSON first.

Comment: And how do I parse that exactly? And do I need to do it client or server side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: JSON is like XML (or YAML, or CSV or ...). It is a textual representation of data, so that you can easily transport it from one location to another. The source *encodes* the data in one of those formats, and the target *decodes* it into its native data types/structures, so that it can access the contained information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dataType: 'json', in ajax call this may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

With all chance, your response is not parsed, use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).